# Configuring VIM ALE plugin with PHPSTAN

Tags: php, vim, vim-plugin, phpstan

I am using [ALE](https://github.com/w0rp/ale) for my PHP developing.
There is possibility to use `phpstan` as one of linters, but no matter what I do there is notification that `phpstan` cannot load class / method definitions:

```
Function foo not found while trying to analyse it - autoloading is probably not configured properly.
```

Default configuration of `ALE` unfortunately does not help, because it expects `phpstan` to be in `$PATH`, and even if it is there it still complains about missing autoloading.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is `git` and `composer` specific.

I have not found good solution without either any vcs or `composer`.

So first of all we assume that there is `composer` being used in project, so there is `autoload.php` file generated. If you are not using this feature you probably should, because it maps classes to files and makes autoloading simple.

Unfortunately using global `phpstan` binary is futile. This is because of `phpstan` looks in current directory for autoload or neon config file that tells it where to look for class definitions. So if you don't want to be forced to open each file in project from root project's directory, then there should be another solution.

Using `phpstan` binary installed by `composer` in your project (in `vendor/bin/phpstan`) solves this problem. Local binary is using the same `autoload.php` and correctly finds each class definition. So we need to tell ale where `phpstan` binary is.

Inserting in `vimrc` file (or better in `.vim/ftplugin/php.vim`) following line:

```
let g:ale_php_phpstan_executable = system('if ! type git &> /dev/null; then echo phpstan; else PSE=`git rev-parse --show-toplevel 2> /dev/null`/vendor/bin/phpstan; if [ -x "$PSE" ]; then echo -n $PSE; else echo phpstan; fi; fi')
```

It tells ALE path to `phpstan` executable, which is determined by running shell comand.

`if ! type git` part checks if there is `git` command in system. If not, then default `phpstan` text is being returned to variable.

`git rev-parse --show-toplevel` is trying to find out whether we are in `git` repository and what is it's top level directory. When found correctly, it determines path to `phpstan` by adding `/vendor/bin/phpstan` to top level directory. This is where locally installed `phpstan` should reside.
If there is no such file or it is not executable, then default `phpstan` variable value is being returned.